# Error when pushing docker image to registry in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, docker, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a Jenkinsfile to try to push a docker image to my local docker registry in the Jenkins build pipeline plugin.  I understand from reading the docs that you should be able to push an image with an optional tagname:

`Image.push([tagname])`

I've got the following code at the moment

```
  stage('Initialise environment') {
   checkout scm
   db = docker.build('oracle', 'docker/oracle').run("-p 49160:22 -p 49161:1521")
   wlp = docker.build('liberty', 'docker/liberty').run("-p 9080:9080 --link=${db.id}:oracle")
  }
  stage('Push image to registry') {
      docker.withRegistry('https://localhost:5000') {
          db.push()
          wlp.push()
      }
     }
```

It's failing at the first push() with the following error:

> Failure: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   static org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.push() is
>   applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions:
>   use([Ljava.lang.Object;), use(java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure),
>   use(java.lang.Class, groovy.lang.Closure), dump(),
>   is(java.lang.Object), each(groovy.lang.Closure)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I made the following changes and it appears to have fixed that issue:

```
   dbImage = docker.build('oracle', 'docker/oracle')
   db = dbImage.run("-p 49160:22 -p 49161:1521")
   wlpImage = docker.build('liberty', 'docker/liberty')
   wlp = wlpImage.run("-p 9080:9080 --link=${db.id}:oracle")
  }
  stage('Push image to registry') {
      docker.withRegistry('https://localhost:5000') {
          dbImage.push()
          wlpImage.push()
      }
     }
```

Reading the documentation again I can now see run() returns a handle to the running container, whereas push() can only be called on the image object returned from build()

Comment: Where is that documentation? I think it's quite unclear what types are returned.

Comment: You can see the documentation in your jenkins instance http://<jenkins>/pipeline-syntax/globals

Comment: In my case, I was missing curly braces after the withRegistry() call. I had to enclose the "push" calls on those curly braces, but I failed to notice that pattern on tutorials and even on the docs. Your question and answer helped me notice that.